# How to get string from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON object:

```
[{"query":"Apple"}]
```

How can I store just the string `"Apple"` in a variable from this JSON object?

Im using NodeJS

Comment: which language are you using ?

Comment: `var query= object[0]['query']`  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asuming you are using javascript you can do this

```
var obj= '[{"query":"Apple"}]';
var arr = JSON.parse(obj);
alert(arr[0].query);
```